# "Iterating until" with monads

Tags: haskell

I have something like this, which is working:

```
main = do
  let p = something :: MyType
  p' <- newP p
  p'' <- newP p'
  p''' <- newP p''
  print p'''
```

See the pattern? I want to repeat this until a certain condition is met, or until a maximum number of iterations passed.

I found `Control.Monad.Loops.iterateUntil`, but I can't get it to work. Here's the code I have (`check` looks something like this `check :: MyType -> Bool`):

```
main = do
  let p = something :: MyType
  let stopCondition (i, p) = i == 100 || check p
  let run (i, p) = (i + 1, newP p)
  p' <- iterateUntil stopCondition (run (0, p))
  print p'
```

It doesn't even compile.

Note that it's important that each time this thing runs, the result of `run` is fed to the next iteration (I'm not sure `iterateUntil` will do that).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you want to use `iterateUntilM` which has type `(a -> Bool) -> (a -> m a) -> a -> m a`, where the state type `a` is `(Int, MyType)`. Then `run` should look like:

```
let run (i, p) = fmap (\p' -> (i + 1, p')) (newP p)
```

then you can do

```
(_, p') <- iterateUntilM stopCondition run (0, p)
```

Comment: I'm getting a compile error on `run`: "Non type-variable argument in the constraint: MonadRandom ((,) t) (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this) When checking that 'run' has the inferred type". Any idea why? (I tested doing `type MyType = Int`, `check p = p == 0`, and a simple function for `newP` that just substracts 1 from `p`)

Comment: @cambraca - Sorry, you can use `fmap` instead of `>>=`, see update.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks! I'll look up both of those, I haven't used them yet (just starting with Haskell..)